# Problems binding keys in MenuItem's with IsCheckable="True", why?

Tags: wpf

This MenuItem does not switch to checked when I press Alt+S, why?

```
<Menu>
   <MenuItem Header="_Other">
      <MenuItem
          Header="_Show Expanded Names ?"
          IsCheckable="True"
          StaysOpenOnClick="True"
          InputGestureText="Alt+S"
          IsChecked="{Binding ShowExpandedName}" />
   </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

NOTE: ShowExpandedName is defined as follows in the DataContext. The MenuItem is checked correctly when I click on it with the mouse.

```
bool _ShowExpandedName;
public bool ShowExpandedName
{
     get { return _ShowExpandedName; }
     set
          {
              if (value != _ShowExpandedName)
              {
                  _ShowExpandedName = value;
                  this.NotifyPropertyChanged("ShowExpandedName");
              }
          }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "_" trick is supposed to work on visible menu items. In this case I'd have to do Alt-O first to open the "_Other" submenu and then press S to choose the item "*Show Expanded Names ?".
I guess the moral of this is that using "*" is not the same as adding a key binding to the command itself!

Answer (score 0):

you need to make ShowExpandedName a dependencyProperty so that the change in its value is reported to the menuItem

see there:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.aspx

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to explain that ShowExpandedName does NotifyPropertyChange. I've edited my question to clarify that point.

Comment: ah... ok then :p. Now, in your treatment for Alt+S, do you by any chance change directly the _ShowExpandedName variable? this would bypass the Notification and hence the behavior you're having. Better use the Set() function there

Comment: I don't understand why you're not using a dependencyProperty though... MS recommend using them rather than plain properties in terms of performance: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613546.aspx

Comment: I see your point... but no. I don't change _ShowExpandedName directly. Furthermore, as I've explained in the edits, if I click with the mouse the MenuItem the item correctly toggles between checked and unchecked, which means that the binding is actually working correctly.

Comment: well, the mouse click is irrelevant here, since it would check/uncheck the button by default anyway (except if you've made some Handlers for this event that are not mentionned here), so from what you wrote, I do not consider this as a proof that the binding works (you could better check the binding by using an other control like a button to update the ShowExpandedName property from code behind, on the Click() event for instance)... I'm still trying to think about what can be the issue there, but no luck yet

Comment: You are missing this: IsChecked="{Binding ShowExpandedName}". In fact, I put a breakpoint in the setter and it is being called after the mouse click.

Comment: this is a proof :) but see my other answer below

Answer (score 0):

I think I found:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/system.windows.controls.menuitem.inputgesturetext%28VS.85%29.aspx

> Notes
>
> This property does not associate the input gesture with the menu item it simply adds text to the menu item. For information on how to associate a command with a menu item see: Command.

Comment: Now you are missing the "_" in Header="_Show Expanded Names ?". This will set the key bonding.

Comment: hmm yes, but it will still not trigger any action in the code behind since it will not trigger any event. I do not see how it could check/uncheck the menu this way. You should have a command/event fired when "ALT+S" is called on your menuItem that changes the value of ShowExpandedName in code behind. Without code behind, I do not think that the item will check itself on a keyboard action defined like this

Comment: Don't forget that IsChecked="{Binding ShowExpandedName}" is a two way binding. That's why _ShowExpandedName gets changed by the mouse click.

Comment: I do not forget it, but I think it does so only because the "click" event on a clickable menu checks it by default, whereas a keyboard triggered action will not do so unless you specify it in code behind (I don't know If i made my thoughts clear)

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort David. But as I said, the breakpoint in the setter gets hit after the mouse click, as I wrote in the first place. There is some other problem here.

Comment: I've found something to illustrate what I mean: http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.controls.menuitem.onaccesskey%28VS.85%29.aspx  . I tend to think that the access key (the "_S" in the header) does not trigger anything on the menuItem and does not check it even if it is checkable, unless you spefify it in code behind (by overriding the ""MenuItem.OnAccessKey method for instance)

Comment: David, I had forgotten that the MenuItem was nested inside another <MenuItem Header="_Other">...</MenuItem>. The "_" trick is supposed to work only for visible menues. Therefore the shortcut to get to the option "_Show Expanded Names" would be Alt+O and then S. This makes sense, and I think it's by design. I hope the missing piece of information didnt waste your time in the first place.

Comment: nothing to worry about, I'm glad you found the source of your pb and the solution :)